# Bootstrap modal popup open when tap close

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have created bootstrap model for asking customer feedback. This model will show when user try to close tap or browser. Help me.

**Model :**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="popupBG1">

                <div class="popupCTARow">
                    <div class="popupCTA1">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ok</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popupCTA2">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myModal1").modal('show');
        });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't show bootstrap modal when users try to leave, but you can show prompt, if that's what you want:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

https://codepen.io/kastriotcunaku/pen/xLrVRb

Comment: @user2172424 - You can't stop closing tab and show modal. First you need to prompt to user if he want to stay or leave. If he chose to stay, then you can show bootstrap modal. Check the demo here: https://codepen.io/kastriotcunaku/pen/xLrVRb
(To make prompt work, user first needs to interact with page; for test try clicking on body, then closing tab)

Comment: Try this and use a pop up window during the unload event:  window.open("To survey page...");   Just wont work with users who's browsers default to blocking pop ups unless the site is white listed.